# Ignoring "//" in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple mysql query like this: 
`INSERT INTO ftpt VALUES (0,ftp://ftp.somewhere.com);` 
As you see, there is "//" in my code which i dont know how to make mysql ignore that, altough it may seem silly
 to you , I couldnt find anything nowhere.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals must be enclosed in single quotes ([as documented in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html)) <sup>(Note that using double quotes is non-standard SQL and will not work on other standard-compliant databases. So it's best to always use single quotes)</sup>

```
INSERT INTO ftpt VALUES (0, 'ftp://ftp.somewhere.com');
```

It's also good coding style to explicitly state the columns of the table:

```
INSERT INTO ftpt (id, url) VALUES (0, 'ftp://ftp.somewhere.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add apostrophe

```
INSERT INTO ftpt VALUES (0,'ftp://ftp.somewhere.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

your query almost right, your just missing `single quotes` you should try this like this:

> INSERT INTO ftpt VALUES (0,'ftp://ftp.somewhere.com');